Select element not preceded by another in CSS
Consider this snippet:


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">️</div>
  <div class="text">paintings</div>
</div>



The icon may or may not be present.
What I'm trying to achieve is that, if the icon is not present, some left padding is added to .text.
How do I do that? I tried a few combinations of :has, :not and + (the next-sibling combinator), to no avail.
Essentially, I want to select .text, but only if it is not preceded by .icon.

.text:not(.icon + .text) should do the trick


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.text:not(.icon + .text) {
  padding-left: 24px;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">️</div>
  <div class="text">paintings</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">paintings</div>
</div>




Thank you! I will accept your answer as it is simpler

.wrapper:not(:has(div.icon)) div.text
should do it.
Example 1 (with icon)


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.wrapper:not(:has(div.icon)) div.text {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">️</div>
  <div class="text">paintings</div>
</div>



Example 2 (without icon)


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.wrapper:not(:has(div.icon)) div.text {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">paintings</div>
</div>




Yes! Thanks. I was just going to add my own answer as I managed to find the same solution, but you were faster. Thanks again!
